# Is there a way to change default thickness of errorbar caps in matplotlib using .mplstyle files

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to set a default cap thickness for matplotlib errorbar plots to match my default linewidth using a .mplstyle file.
I would expect to be able to do it using:

```
errorbar.capthick: 2
```

since this is the option that is used when calling the errorbar method. This doesn't work, so I tried the old argument:

```
errorbar.markeredgewidth: 2
```

But unsurprisingly this didn't work either.

Does anyone know if it possible to set the default errorbar cap thickness using an .mplstyle document, or can this only be changed on a per instance basis?

Comment: The [reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar.html) has this explanation. **capthick: float, default: None** _An alias to the keyword argument markeredgewidth (a.k.a. mew). This setting is a more sensible name for the property that controls the thickness of the error bar cap in points. For backwards compatibility, if mew or markeredgewidth are given, then they will over-ride capthick. This may change in future releases.__

Comment: Thanks, but that is not really the issue here. I have no trouble changing the mew/capthickness on a per plot basis. What i want to do is to control this from a .mplstyle file, but neither capthick/mew/markeredgewidth works from this document. This is strange as other options like capsize can be set from a .mplstyle file.